# Meaning of the word "why" in context

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/5A_o-nU5s2U). It is at around 8 minute and 13 second. Here it goes:

> Napoleon had plans to reconstruct France's empire in North America that it had lost most of in the 7 Years War, and to do this he needed tons of money from France's most valuable colony, Saint-Domingue. And the best way to maximize profits? **Why**, to reintroduce slavery, of course.

Did the presenter mean *why not to reintroduce...*?

Comment: That's what the comma is for -- to indicate that _why_ has a special intonation as an interjection and is not being used as an interrogative or relative.

Answer (score 1):

> Why? Because ...

would  be a so-called "rhetorical question" and its answer. But here it functions also like "*Well then*, let me tell you the answer to that question..."

Compare:

> Why, look at how much the two of you have grown! Come here and give grandma a
>   big hug.